# Regular expression group matching

Tags: python, regex, matching, regex-group

I am trying to search for sequence of binary digits separated by white space like this:

```
>>> seq = '0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0'
```

so, I create the regex:

```
>>> pat = r'(\b[01]\b)+'
```

but following search returns only one digit:

```
>>> re.search(pat, seq).group(0)
'0'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, just missing a space in the pattern.  Try `pat = r'\b([01] )*[01]\b'`

```
>>> import re
>>> seq = '0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0'
>>> pat = r'\b([01] )*[01]\b'
>>> re.search(pat, seq).group(0)
'0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0'
>>> re.search(pat, 'spam and 0 0 0 1 0eggs').group(0)
'0 0 0 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex has no way to match the whitespace, so it can only match a single character.  You can either use the same regex with `re.findall()` to get all matches in the string, or modify your regex so it will continue matching even if it encounters white space.

Here is an example using `re.findall()`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\b[01]\b)+', '0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0')
['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0']
```

Or by changing the regex to `(\b[01]\b\s?)+` you can get the entire sequence in a single match:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\b[01]\b\s?)+', '0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0').group(0)
'0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I see why. The \b matches an empty string at boundary of a word, but it does not match a white space, so I need to spell out a \s after a word for matching.